# Select-AzureRmSubscription : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I have created the Powershell Runbook, and added all the required details and valid values. Still I am facing the error for `Select-AzureRmSubscription` command. The error I am getting all the time is

> Select-AzureRmSubscription : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.

I am using below connection setting in Powershell runbook:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

try
{

    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "

    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName 

    "Logging in to Azure..."

    Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId
    $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint
    $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
}
catch {

    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection) 
    {

        $ErrorMessage = "Connection
        $connectionName not found."

        throw $ErrorMessage

    } else{

        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception

        throw $_.Exception
    }
}


fetch-group-memberships | Select-Object UserName, PrincipalName, GroupName, AzureGroupName |Sort-Object GroupName| Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path
'MEMBERSHIP.csv' 

#=======================================================================================

# Select the subscription you are going to work with

#=======================================================================================
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId
"[removed for security purpose]"

#Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "BIG" | Select-AzureRmSubscription

#=======================================================================================

# Set the Current Storage Account to the approperiate location

#=======================================================================================

Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -StorageAccountName devapacbi01 -ResourceGroupName dev-rgp-apac-01

#=======================================================================================

# Capture the file that is local to automation and save to Storage Blob

#=======================================================================================

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container bi-app-carm-im -File ADGROUP_MEMBERSHIP.csv -Blob _MEMBERSHIP_AL.csv -Force
```

Even if the subscription id is correct it keeps throwing an error as above.

Comment: If you run the runbook in the portal, you are already in the subscription, no need to use `Select-AzureRmSubscription`, then it will work fine.

Comment: If the subscription that you select is in your current tenant?

Comment: @CharlesXu :  Yes. that subscription is in current tenant

Comment: @JoyWang : I tried removing Select-AzureRmSubscription command from the script , then I am facing below error for next command : Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount : 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.
At line:147 char:1

Comment: Are the runbook and the storage which you used in the same subscription?

Comment: @JoyWang, Yes, it is.

Comment: You can get all subscriptions in the current tenant with the command `Get-AzSubscription -TenantId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"` to have a check if the subscription is right.

Comment: Actually what you want to do? Upload file to blob storage?

Comment: @JoyWang  , I tried to get the subscription id value in variable using  Get-AzureRmSubscription -TenantId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" and pass that variable  value to Select-AzureRmSubscription but same error

Comment: $currentAzureContext = Get-AzureRmContext
$tenant = $currentAzureContext.Tenant.Id

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $tenant

Answer (score 3):

this means you do not have permissions to do so. you need to assign proper permissions to the account you are using for the runbook

Comment: My account is having contributor role which is I guess sufficient to do this.

Comment: doesnt matter what your account has, azure runbook doesnt have permissions

Comment: So how we can use the connection which is created to use current service account to connect with app ?

Comment: sorry, i dont understand the question

Comment: So freaking annoying how vague the error message is. This answer is correct. If you don't have permissions to the subscription, you will receive this bizarre error message.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to `Select-AzureRmSubscription` because runbook connection is only tied to on subscription.

Also keep in mid the runbook is running on a environment setup to run your script, I prefer to stay away from `Set` environment commands.

Removing the subscription line and fixing lines below should work.

`$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -StorageAccountName devapacbi01 -ResourceGroupName dev-rgp-apac-01`

`Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container bi-app-carm-im -File ADGROUP_MEMBERSHIP.csv -Blob _MEMBERSHIP_AL.csv -Context $storageAccount.Context -Force`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I tired above solution but getting below error now : Get-AzureRmStorageAccount : 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.
At line:154 char:19
+ ... geAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -StorageAccountName airliquides ...
CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmStorageAccount], ValidationException
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.GetAzureStorageAccountCommand
 
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent : Could not get the storage context.  Please pass in a storage context or set the current

Comment: You connection is off, commands worked in my runbook.  Look at connection carefully. https://i.imgur.com/oHzoG8K.png

Answer (score 0):

Its Solved! You guys were correct, it was an issue with correct permissions with Automation Account only. We should have a access as a contributor on your storage account. After giving right permissions to automation RunAs (contributor on your storage account) it worked and ran successfully. Than you all again.